# Angular Slickgrid filtering on multiple columns

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

Is there a way to filter on multiple columns with angular-slickgrid ?

I have columns showing the same information in different regions, and I'd like the user to be able to use one filter to get any row matching regardless of which region (column) matches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No you cannot (but there's a longer Yes option below), there's a reason why each filter are shown on top of each column and it's because they are associated with that said column (by looping through each column definition, these filters are being created dynamically). You can however use another column when filtering, with `queryFieldFilter` or with `queryFieldNameGetterFn` depending on the data but again that will only be associated to 1 column at a time.

Does that mean that you cannot do it at all? Not necessarily, you could provide a different `filter` implementation via the SlickGrid DataView `dataView.setFilter(myFilter);` but if you do that then you'll bypass all the column filters (in other words, none of the default column filters would work anymore when you override the DataView filter method) but maybe that is acceptable for you by making it as a global filter and disabling the filters header row. You can take this SlickGrid [Example](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) to see the code, it has an external filter with multiple conditions and that might work for you.

```js
function myFilter(item, args) {
  if (item["percentComplete"] < args.percentCompleteThreshold) {
    return false;
  }

  if (args.searchString != "" && item["title"].indexOf(args.searchString) == -1) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Basically what I meant to say is that you do have the option to rewrite your own filter implementation but by doing so, you will for sure break the default column filters implementation. I typically never do that because it's more work and also not as effective to have only 1 global search filter but it's up to you and your use case.

It would be easier to just add that column in the grid and ask the user to filter it by region

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

Comment: That looks perfect. I am only using one other filter in the tab, so I don't mind combining them into one, in this specific case that should be fine imho. I'll try that on, thanks for the help and for the great lib !

Comment: Yeah it's probably doable and also the reason why Angular-Slickgrid exist is of course to make it working in Angular but also because SlickGrid is like IKEA, it's a lot customizable but you have to put all the pieces together and that is true for the Filters and many more pieces of the lib, you still have the option to assemble it in different ways for some part.